# Italian citizenship - which consulate?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, italy, italian-citizens, italy-aire

I applied for Italian citizenship by marriage last year. At the time we were living in Switzerland so we did the paperwork through the Zürich consulate.

Now we have moved to London. In theory my wife is supposed to register in the Italian consulate in London, who would then "manage" my case. In a couple of years when the procedure is done I'd get a letter from them, and go apply for a passport.

The problem is I've read terrible, terrible reviews about the consulate in London, whereas dealing with the consulate in Zürich was painless. So we're tempted to not register here and leave the case in Zürich. So in two years I'll get a letter from the consulate in Zürich, and then... would I run into any kind of trouble for not being a resident in Switzerland anymore?

Answer (score 2):

The consulate make just a preliminary verification of autenticity of the documents and forward the request to the Interior Ministry (*Ministero degli Interni*). Since I don't think it is possible to apply twice, your wife should just communicate your new address in London to the Zurich consulate so that they can reach you whenever they have an answer.

AIRE subscription for your wife (and you) can be done in London by email and will probably not interfere (if you want, you can let them known the citizen request protocol number).